# copy a table from different projects and push into an EU result project

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have got several bigquery projects, some EU region and some US region. All projects have '**customers**' dataset and a table inside '**customers**' dataset called '**purchases**'
I want to write a query to copy all the contents of **purchases** table into another table in another project which is called **Results** and it is EU region.
So I created this query:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `customers.purchases`
WHERE
  {{param.location}}='EU'
  AND _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP('{{ ds }}')
UNION ALL
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `customers_EU.purchases`
WHERE
  _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP('{{ ds }}')
AND {{param.location}}='EU'
```

As the **results** project is located in EU, I cannot copy from US into EU, so for US region projects, I created a **customers_EU** dataset and I copy **purchases** table from **customers** dataset into **customers_EU** in the same project. Then the above query checks if the project is EU region then copy from **customers** dataset else copy from **customers_EU** dataset.

But the problem is it fails and it gives an error for a US project:

> customers.purchases was not found in location 'EU'

Yes, that is right, it is not located in EU but the location parameter is US and I am expecting it skip first part of query and return nothing from the first part of query as the condition is not satisfied

Comment: You want an `if` in a script, not `union all`.  Either that, or create a dummy table, perhaps as a view.

Answer (score 1):

One approach you can take can be:

1. Only query **purchases** tables with dataset located in EU (using `UNION ALL`). Set a destination table in a dataset located in EU as well.
2. Only query **purchases** tables with dataset located in the US (using `UNION ALL`). Set a destination table in a dataset located in the US as well.
3. Using the feature **Dataset copy** (BQ transfer service) move (copy) the US dataset created in the step 2 to EU.
4. Create a view that UNION table created in **step 1** with table created in **step 3**.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. There are some restriction on result project so there is no cluster and we can not schedule any task. That final project is just for pushing data into it.

Comment: That should be fine. Instead of a view, you can have a schedule query to push the data into the result project. You can have it in the same project of step 3.